# Facing an Error during Building the project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am building the project in VS2012 and getting the following error , I have searched on Google ,did not found much similar solution,Please provide the solution for the same , Here are the error code snippet  -

```
        MOCing D:\giit\release_17\RTTBorrow\rttBorrowWindow.h
         'moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
         operable program or batch file.
          MOCing D:\giit\release_17\RTTBorrow\rttListView.h
         'moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
         operable program or batch file.
         MOCing D:\giit\release_17\RTTBorrow\rttpassworddialog.h
         'moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
         operable program or batch file.
          MOCing D:\giit\release_17\RTTBorrow\rttpassworddialogimpl.h
          'moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
          operable program or batch file.
          MOCing D:\giit\release_17\RTTBorrow\rttTextEdit.h
         'moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
          operable program or batch file.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.
Thanks !!!
```

Comment: What's the project you build? Provide the detail steps to reproduce that issue.

Comment: @strain Issue got resolved by providing the path of moc.exe for building .

Comment: You can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't tell what project you're trying to build and googling "giit" doesn't give meaningful results, I'm giving a general suggestion.

`moc.exe` is part of Qt build system so you could try installing it. Its website is http://qt.io

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution